# Cannot upload image in django using filefield

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-uploads

I am not able to upload image.

here is my **models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    image = models.FileField(upload_to = 'post/static/images/' , null= True, blank= True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

the image is not getting uploaded to ***'post/static/images/'***

here is the template for uploading the image

```
    {% if post.media %}
    <img src="{{ post.image.url }}" class="img-responsive" />
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: Your code in template is not for uploading an image but to show an image.

Comment: @doru i have to only display the image. but the image is not getting uploaded to the folder i specified

Comment: @Kreloch I am not using any form.Is that a problem

Comment: If you're using linux you should also check the upload folder permisions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many problems with your code:

1. In your model - use the field for image uplaoding `ImageField` (to use `ImageField` you need to have installed [Pillow](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow)):

   ```
   image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images/' , null= True, blank= True)
   ```

   (you will upload the images in a subfolder of the MEDIA_ROOT folder named `images`)
2. Also put the images in the media folder - you have to create one, in the **settings.py** folder add:

   ```
   MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
   MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
   ```
3. To let django serve your media (only for development!) you have to add in your main (from your project directory not from your app folder) **urls.py** file:

   ```
   from django.conf import settings
   from django.conf.urls.static import static

   if settings.DEBUG:
       urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
   ```
4. An example of a simple form to upload an image:

   ```
   <form action="{% url upload_pic %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
       <input id="id_image" type="file" class="" name="image">
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
   </form>
   ```

   where `url_upload_pic` is the (function) view which should handle the upload of the image.

Answer (score 1):

And I think a good thing too.

> MEDIA_ROOT and STATIC_ROOT must have different values. Before
>   STATIC_ROOT was introduced, it was common to rely or fallback on
>   MEDIA_ROOT to also serve static files; however, since this can have
>   serious security implications, there is a validation check to prevent
>   it.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#media-root

What you want to be doing (in development) is to follow this guide:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

> During development, you can serve user-uploaded media files from
>   MEDIA_ROOT using the django.views.static.serve() view.
>
> This is not suitable for production use! For some common deployment
>   strategies, see Deploying static files.
>
> For example, if your MEDIA_URL is defined as /media/, you can do this
>   by adding the following snippet to your urls.py:

Basically, you updload the files to a place in MEDIA_ROOT and then tell django to treat them almost like static. But you don't directly upload to static.