# django does not show images from MEDIA

Tags: django

this is my urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^', include('my_website.urls')),

url(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
url(r'^filer/', include('filer.urls')),
url(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT + os.path.altsep )
```

this is my settings:

```
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG           = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS   = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1']


MEDIA_ROOT  = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "mooimom_id", "user_uploads")
MEDIA_URL   = "/media/"
```

my media files are all in:

C:\wamp64\www\mooimom_django\mooimom_id\user_uploads\folder_name\file_names

static files are mostly in:
C:\wamp64\www\mooimom_django\mooimom_id\static\folder_names

When debug is True, the images works fine, but when i turn it into False, only images from {% static %} shows up. The rest gets 404.

Comment: you are not using dev server in production are you?

Comment: it's localhost (my own computer), not yet in live server

Comment: i am sorry, i don't think i understand your question, i am quite new with Django

Comment: show the settings for media in settings

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot upload image in django using filefield](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43994457/cannot-upload-image-in-django-using-filefield)

Comment: i don't get it, so what do i need to do?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://ericeastwood.com/blog/3/django-setup-for-wamp) help

Comment: Are you using WAMP?

Comment: thanks, but i don't use wamp for my django though, i simply put all my projects in that folder, my web server is pycharm 2017

Comment: i use the "run" and "debug" on pycharm,

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation for the static helper](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development) clearly states, this works only when DEBUG is True.

Comment: but my static files are working fine, it's files from Media folders that are not showing up / 404

Comment: This does not work on DEBUG false: http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/filer_public/93/3e/933e7635-4f20-42d4-aee9-8f9233989ab2/v-neck-maternity-nursing-bra-top.jpg

Comment: But you're using the static helper. It does not work when DEBUG is false. Why won't you set it to true? You should have it set in development anyway as it helps debugging.

Comment: because i want to upload the files to the webserver.

Comment: What? That sentence seems to have no relation to any previous comment. If you want this to work in development, set DEBUG to True.

Comment: sorry, i am quite new with django, what i was trying to do is to make sure my website works even when DEBUG is False, my site is already working when DEBUG is true.

Comment: but when DEBUG is false, the media files all get 404, but the images from {% static %} works.